# Back button using FreshMVVM

Tags: xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

I am trying to add a back button to the toolbar and I have read that it can be done using the following in the constructor

```
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this,true);
```

I have also added the same in xaml in the ContentPage

```
 NavigationPage.HasBackButton="True" NavigationPage.BackButtonTitle="Search"
```

but I cant see my title shown in the toolbar or the arrow for the back button. What am I doing wrong. Is this due to the fact that I am using FreshMVVM

Answer (score 0):

I have got it working now,I was loading the page as a modal and the back button was not showing. Loading the page as a non modal did the trick. However the title of the back button seems to say 'Back' somehow even after specifying a value for the title

**Update**

The title of the previous page was not set , setting it to a value changes the title of the back button to be the same. I thought we could enforce the back button to have a different value through the call from the constructor but that didnt work for me

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. How are you pushing a new navigation withouth PushNewNavigationServiceModal? There's no PushNewNavigationService (non modal).

Comment: @Dpedrinha Have a look at [this article](http://www.tom-walker.ca/?p=5881)

Comment: @Curiousity I didn't see anything relevant in my issue there.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [post by James Montemagno](https://montemagno.com/changing-ioss-back-button-text-in-xamarinforms/). In XAML add the `NavigationPage.BackButtonTitle` to the `ContentPage`. Remember this is set on the page you want to navigate back to, not on the page currently displayed. I'm using this with a [FreshMvvm](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm) project.

```
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core" 
    ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
    x:Class="MyProject.Pages.MyPage"
    NavigationPage.BackButtonTitle="Back"
    Title="My Page Title">
    ...
</ContentPage>
```